# How do I prevent iOS from closing my heart rate monitor when the app is in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've written an iOS app that monitors and saves heart rate data. I started with this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/231-core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor) and while I've added a significant amount of code, this is the core code tracking the heart rate.

To summarize, the app picks up a BLE signal from a standard heart rate sensor worn by the user. It displays and saves this data without any issues. I can even open other apps for short periods of time. However, when I open another app and keep it up for more than a minute or so, the app stops recording. When I reopen it, I'm back at the home screen. To be clear, the app has permission to run in the background and does so without issue for the first minute. This leads me to believe that iOS is freezing my app to save on resources.

I know this has to be possible because the Polar app is able to record heart rate while in the background without issues. I think (hope) I'm just missing one setting or line of code somewhere.

I've given it permission in the XCode project settings
[Project->Signing & Capabilities->Background Modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpEwK.png)

I've also added background modes to plist.info
[plist.info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMSJe.png)

What else do I need to do to keep the app running in the background? I've looked into background tasks but the app needs to be able to run in the background for hours, not minutes.

EDIT: Here is my code. I think I'm just doing read requests.

```
//  newFlightViewController.swift


import Charts
import CoreBluetooth
import NotificationBannerSwift
import UIKit
import UserNotifications


let heartRateServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x180D")
let heartRateMeasurementCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A37")
let bodySensorLocationCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A38")

class newFlightViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var heartRateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bodySensorLocationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var chartView: LineChartView!
    
    
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var heartRatePeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    var lineChart = LineChartView() // chart
    var entries = [ChartDataEntry]()
    var hr_array: [Double] = []
    var time_array: [Double] = []
    var startTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    var warningHR = 80
    var bpm = 0  // Initializing bpm variable as a class variable
    var timeSinceLastNotification = 10000  // We use this to check that we haven't sent a notification recently
    var timeBetweenNotifications = 30
    var timeSinceLastSave = 100
    var timeBetweenSaves = 10
    var items: [Flight]?
    var newFlight: Flight?
    
    
    let userNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
      
      super.viewDidLoad()
//        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
      lineChart.delegate = self  // chart
      self.userNotificationCenter.delegate = self
      self.requestNotificationAuthorization()  // Notification Capability
  //    self.sendNotification(var timeInterval: Double)  //Notification Capability

//       Make the digits monospaces to avoid shifting when the numbers change
        heartRateLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 100.0, weight: .regular)
        self.newFlight = Flight(context: self.context)
        self.newFlight?.flight_id = randomString(length: 64)
        self.newFlight?.date = Date()
        self.newFlight?.instructor = "INSTRUCTOR"
      
    }
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    
    @IBAction func saveData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Saving Data")
        
        
        let saveBanner = StatusBarNotificationBanner(title: "Data Saved", style: .success)
        saveBanner.show()
    }
    
    func fetchFlights() -> [Flight]?{
        do {
            self.items = try context.fetch(Flight.fetchRequest())
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SupplementaryViewController().tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            
        }
        return self.items
    }
    
    func onHeartRateReceived(_ heartRate: Int) {
        heartRateLabel.text = String(heartRate)
        print("BPM: \(heartRate)")

        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: entries)
        set.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()
        //
        let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set)

        set.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        set.drawFilledEnabled = true
        set.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
        set.colors = [UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)]
        set.lineWidth = 2
        set.drawValuesEnabled = false
        chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 40
        chartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 40
        chartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 160
        chartView.rightAxis.axisMaximum = 160


        chartView.data = data
      
    }
  }
    

  extension newFlightViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
      switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
          print("central.state is .unknown")
        case .resetting:
          print("central.state is .resetting")
        case .unsupported:
          print("central.state is .unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
          print("central.state is .unauthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
          print("central.state is .poweredOff")
        case .poweredOn:
          print("central.state is .poweredOn")
          centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [heartRateServiceCBUUID])
      @unknown default:
          print("Unknown switch case in function centralManagerDidUpdateState")
      }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
      print("\nCentral\n\n")
      print(central)
      print("\n\n")
      
      print("\nHeart Rate Peripheral\n\n")
      print(peripheral)
      print("\n\n")
      heartRatePeripheral = peripheral
      heartRatePeripheral.delegate = self

      centralManager.stopScan()
//      centralManager.connect(heartRatePeripheral)
        centralManager.connect(heartRatePeripheral, options: [CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnConnectionKey:true, CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey: true])

      
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
      print("Connected!")
      heartRatePeripheral.discoverServices([heartRateServiceCBUUID])
    }
  }

  extension newFlightViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
      guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }

      for service in services {
        print(service)
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
      }
    }
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,
                    error: Error?) {
      guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }

      for characteristic in characteristics {
        print(characteristic)
        if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
          print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
          peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
        }
        if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
          print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
          peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
        }
      }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                    error: Error?) {
      switch characteristic.uuid {
        case heartRateMeasurementCharacteristicCBUUID:
          self.bpm = heartRate(from: characteristic)
          let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        onHeartRateReceived(self.bpm)
        entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(timestamp - startTime), y: Double(self.bpm)))
          hr_array.append(Double(self.bpm))
          time_array.append(Double(timestamp))
        self.timeSinceLastNotification += 1
        
          if (self.bpm > self.warningHR && self.timeSinceLastNotification > self.timeBetweenNotifications) {
          self.sendNotification(timeInterval: 0.01)  //Notification Capability
          self.timeSinceLastNotification = 0
        }

        default:
          print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
      }
    }

    private func bodyLocation(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> String {
      guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value,
        let byte = characteristicData.first else { return "Error" }

      switch byte {
        case 0: return "Other"
        case 1: return "Chest"
        case 2: return "Wrist"
        case 3: return "Finger"
        case 4: return "Hand"
        case 5: return "Ear Lobe"
        case 6: return "Foot"
        default:
          return "Reserved for future use"
      }
    }
    
    private func heartRate(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> Int {
      guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return -1 }
      let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)

      let firstBitValue = byteArray[0] & 0x01
      if firstBitValue == 0 {
        // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd byte
        return Int(byteArray[1])
      } else {
        // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd and 3rd bytes
        return (Int(byteArray[1]) << 8) + Int(byteArray[2])
      }
    }
    
    func requestNotificationAuthorization() {
      // Authorization options
      let authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.init(arrayLiteral: .alert, .badge, .sound)
      
      self.userNotificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (success, error) in
        if let error = error {
          print("Error: ", error)
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    func sendNotification(timeInterval: Double) {
      let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      
      // Add content to to notificationContent
      notificationContent.title = "High Heart Rate"
      notificationContent.body = "Heart rate has exceeded \(self.warningHR) bpm"
      notificationContent.badge = NSNumber(value: 3)
      
      
      
      // Add an attachment to the notification content
      if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "generic_hr_heart", withExtension: "png") {
        if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "generic_hr_heart", url: url, options: nil) {
            notificationContent.attachments = [attachment]
        }
      }
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false)
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "highHR", content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)
        
        userNotificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
          if let error = error {
            print("Notification Error: ", error)
          }
        }
      
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      completionHandler()
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        completionHandler([.badge, .sound, .banner])
      } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
      }
    }
    
    @IBAction func saveAndEndFlight(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Ending Flight")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        //        performSegue(withIdentifier: "recordFlightStatsSegue", sender: self)
    }
      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
          var vc = segue.destination as! GradeSheetViewController
          
          self.newFlight?.hr_array = self.hr_array
          self.newFlight?.time_array = self.time_array
         
          
          
          do {
              try self.context.save()
          }
          catch {
              print("Error Saving Flight")
          }
          self.fetchFlights()
          
          SupplementaryViewController().fetchFlights()
          
          vc.timeArray = self.time_array
          vc.newFlight = self.newFlight
      }
      
      func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
      }
  }
```

This is my first time coding in Swift and almost all of my experience has been in Python so I apologize in advance for my lack of understanding.

Comment: Are you using Bluetooth notifications to receive data from the heart rate monitor or are you polling using `read` requests?  Have you set up Bluetooth state restoration when you create your CBCentralManager and added the appropriate code to your `didFinishLaunching`?  Do you minimise the amount of work you do when you get a sample? Check the device console log or analytics data (under privacy in settings) for jettison events for your app.

Comment: Only certain classes of apps are allowed to keep getting CPU time from the background. It used to be VoIP apps, music apps, and turn-by-turn navigation apps. I haven't looked at HealthKit, but I suspect that apps that use HealthKit are also allowed to have background time if they are set up correctly.

Comment: I don't think this is even HealthKit. This is interacting with a Bluetooth heart rate monitor directly. Interacting with BLE accessories is a background mode, but there are still absolute cpu time limits

Comment: Updated my question to include my code. I think I'm just using read requests but I'm not entirely sure. I have not set up Bluetooth state restoration or created a ```didFinishLaunching```. Do you have a link to a tutorial or other resource for Bluetooth state restoration? The code is fairly messy and inefficient. Essentially, every second I want to append the heart rate to an array to be saved in CoreData. I've been able to access the device console log, but is there a way to find the log specific to my app? There seem to be a lot of unrelated logs and they're only labeled by date.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the below selection if not already.
[image]

[image]

The Bluetooth LE accessory typically makes the app still usable in the BG. (I also set up the `isIdleTimerDisabled` as well.)